# Can hardware identifcation be evaded/spoofed?

Tags: hardware, identity, vnc

If I'm not wrong, one of the many ways companies track and collect data of people through the internet is by identifying their hardware. Getting the monitor resolution, figuring what CPU it is, etc. So are there any methods of resisting this? I had a potential idea of evading the monitor thing by VNCing into another computer(probably a raspberry pi) and doing whatever you needed to do, sense it wouldn't be technically connected to a monitor but still giving a video output?

Comment: For browser fingerprinting you can use a clean Virtual Machine each time you browse the internet.

Comment: Not sure if the display size can be retrieved through a browser, but the size of the browser window sure can.